What is the average strength for 'maxed' Shadow Assassin gear?
As of right now I deal about ~80,000 damage per hit outside of dungeons and ~200k - 1.8 mil in dungeons with my current gear.
My current gear/stats:

Legendary SA (Shadow Assassin) armor (Full set, enchanted, 2 stars, reforged with Ancient)
Legendary SA Cloak, Ender Gauntlet, Ender Necklace, and Ender Belt
Giant Cleaver (Enchanted, 5 stars, reforged with Sharp)
Level 45 Epic Lion pet
~260 Magical Power (MP)

This gives me 538 strength and 789 crit damage. I know that I am far from 'maxed' on any of these, and I am working on getting more MP, but I wanted to ask what the average strength for a 'maxed' setup is so that I can know what damage to expect when I get there.
As far as I am aware what's considered 'maxed' is:

5 Dungeon stars on every gear
Fully enchanted (In this case just the ones you get from the enchanting table)
Reforged (In this case ancient for the armor, withered for the weapon)
Level 100 Pet
Minimum 300 MP

Skill levels also play a role, but I'm mainly focusing on how the gear you're using contributes to damage since I'll be leveling those as I go.
Thanks!

This seems to be a little subjective.

@Daemons Sorry if it seems that way, how could I improve it? I'm always looking on how to improve my questions. What I'm trying to ask right now is basically just what the most common reforges / damage numbers are during the early/mid game stages.

Good on you! To me, it read as subjective because where game stages (early, middle, late) start may depend on the person. Also, the damage someone “should” be doing in a game stage depends completely on what they’re using, among other factors.

The last two paragraphs should also (probably) be two separate questions (as it stands, it's probably too broad) - the first of the last two paragraphs should stay here, but but the last paragraph should be removed and expanded into its own separate question (if you want to make it its own question, that is).

Alright, thanks! I'll be editing soon to hopefully address some of this
